# Nested linked-list in c

Tags: c, linked-list, nested

My function AddItemToClient doesnt seem to work I'm not sure if its because of find function or because of AddItemToClient function but the output is strange. When I try to add item to another client than first one, it doesnt work but works propely only to first client but aswell adds to every existing client same item could somebody explain why?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
struct date
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    struct date* next;
};
struct item
{
    char item_name[30];
    char item_state[30];
    double item_price;
    char item_status[30];
    double item_price_if_not;
    struct date *issue_date;
    struct item *next;
};
struct client
{
    char client_name[30];
    char client_last_name[30];
    struct item *item_data;
    struct client *next;
};
//ADD CLIENT//
void AddClient(struct client **head, char name[30], char last_name[30])
{
    if((*head) == NULL)
    {
        *head = malloc(sizeof(struct client));
        strcpy((*head)->client_name,name);
        strcpy((*head)->client_last_name,last_name);
        (*head)->next = NULL;
        (*head)->item_data = NULL;
    }
    else
{
    struct client *temp;
    temp = (*head);
    //             //
    while(temp->next)
    temp=temp->next;
    //              //
    (temp->next) = malloc(sizeof(struct client));
    strcpy(temp->next->client_name,name);
    strcpy(temp->next->client_last_name,last_name);
    temp->next->next = NULL;
    temp->next->item_data = NULL;
}
}
//ADD CLIENT END//
//////////////////
//FIND TO ADD//
struct client *FindToAdd(struct client *head, char named[30],char last_name[30])
{
    struct client *current = head;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        if((strcmp(current->client_name,named) == 0 )&& (strcmp(current->client_last_name,last_name) == 0))
        {
            printf("Client found :%s %s\n",current->client_name,current->client_last_name);
            return current;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    return (NULL);
}
//FIND TO ADD END//
///////////////////
//ADD ITEM TO CLIENT//
void AddItemToClient(struct client *head, char item_name[30], char item_state[30], double price, char status[30], double price_if_not, int day, int month, int year)
{
    struct item* it = malloc(sizeof(struct item));
    strcpy(it->item_name, item_name);
    strcpy(it->item_state, item_state);
    strcpy(it->item_status, status);
    it->item_price = price;
    it->item_price_if_not = price_if_not;
    it->issue_date = malloc(sizeof(struct date));
    it->issue_date->day = day;
    it->issue_date->month = month;
    it->issue_date->year = year;
    it->next = NULL;
    it->issue_date->next = NULL;
    if (head->item_data == NULL)
    {
        head->item_data = it;
    }
    else
    {
        struct item* node = head->item_data;
        while (node->next != NULL) node = node->next;
        node->next = it;
    }
}
//ADD ITEM TO CLIENT END//
//////////////////////////
// DISPLAY//
void Display(struct client *head)
    {int i=1,b=1;
    struct client *current;
    current = head;
        while(current != NULL)
        {
           printf("[%d] Client name:%s %s \n",i, current->client_name, current->client_last_name);
           struct item *CurrentItem = head->item_data;
           while(CurrentItem != NULL)
           {
             printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
             printf("[%d] \n",b);
             printf("Item name: %s\n",CurrentItem->item_name);
             printf("Item state: %s\n",CurrentItem->item_state);
             printf("Item status: %s\n",CurrentItem->item_status);
             printf("Item price: %lf\n",CurrentItem->item_price);
             printf("Item price if debt wasnt paid: %lf\n",CurrentItem->item_price_if_not);
             printf("Issue date: %d/%d/%d\n",CurrentItem->issue_date->day,CurrentItem->issue_date->month,CurrentItem->issue_date->year);
             printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
             CurrentItem = CurrentItem->next;
             b++;
           }
           current=current->next;
           i++;
        }
    }
//DISPLAY END//
///////////////
int main()
{
    struct client* List = NULL;
         int choice;
         char name[30];
         char client_name[30];
         char client_named[30];
         char client_last_named[30];
          char client_last_name[30];
          char item_name[30];
          char item_state[30];
          char to_find_name[30];
          char to_find_last_name[30];
          double price;
          char status[30];
          double price_if_not;
          int day,month,year;
         scanf( "%d", &choice );
    while( choice != 6)
    {
        printf("Option 1: New person:\nOption 2: Display\nOption 3: Add item to person\n");
    switch( choice )
    {
    case 1:
     printf( "New person: \n" );
                printf("Provide client name\n");
                scanf("%s",client_name);
                printf("Provide client last name\n");
                scanf("%s",client_last_name);
                AddClient(&List,client_name,client_last_name);
                break;
    case 2:
     printf("Display\n");
                Display(List);
                break;
    case 3:
    printf("Add item to person: \n");
    struct client *temporal = NULL;
    printf("Name of desired person\n");
      scanf("%s",client_named);
    printf("Last name of desired person\n");
      scanf("%s",client_last_named);
    temporal = FindToAdd(List,client_named,client_last_named);
    printf("Item name\n");
      scanf("%s",item_name);
    printf("Item state\n");
    scanf("%s",item_state);
    printf("Item price\n");
      scanf("%lf",&price);
    printf("Item status\n");
    scanf("%s",status);
    printf("Item price if debt wasnt paid\n");
      scanf("%lf",&price_if_not);
    printf("Issue date: day\n");
    scanf("%d",&day);
    printf("Issue date: month\n");
    scanf("%d",&month);
    printf("Issue date: year\n");
    scanf("%d",&year);
    AddItemToClient(temporal,item_name,item_state,price,status,price_if_not,day,month,year);
    break;
    case 4:
     printf("Name of desired person\n");
      scanf("%s",to_find_name);
    printf("Last name of desired person\n");
      scanf("%s",to_find_last_name);
    FindToAdd(List,to_find_name,to_find_last_name);
    break;
    default:
            printf( "Invalid choice.\n\n" );
            break;
        }
        printf( "? " );
      scanf( "%d", &choice );
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks identical to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205697/nested-singly-linked-list-c. If you don't get answers, try to improve the question and provide more information, instead of simply repeating it.

Comment: In my previous question function AddItemToClient didn't work at all was overwriting previous nodes, right now at least for first node links are done correctly so i thought that problem right now was different most likely because of find function. So I think it finds tail of item so I dont think it's same problem still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is here:

```
           struct item *CurrentItem = head->item_data;
```

should be

```
       struct item *CurrentItem = current->item_data;
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think the problem could be display function was thinking all the time I was just doing something wrong in find or additem functions.